# Can I dual boot Ubuntu server 14.04 on Macbook Yosemite OS X 10.10.5?

Tags: dual-boot, server, macosx

I am learning how to operate Ubuntu Server. I have seen how to dual boot Ubuntu desktop to my Macbook running Yosemite, but is there a difference between that and loading Ubuntu Server?

Comment: Why do you want Ubuntu Server on a Macbook?

Comment: Like @Zacharee1 said, why on earth are you trying to run Ubuntu server on a macbook?

Comment: Because I have a macbook and I'm doing a little course on learning basic ubuntu commands. The person teaching it is using ubuntu server. Thanks for the answer Daniel

Answer (score 0):

There should be no operational difference in installation, except you might not get a GUI desktop, since it's the server edition...Hope you know bash!

Comment: Can you mark as accepted then?